# Como ler arquivos CSV em Java

Tags: java, csv

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web, onde após o usuário realizar o upload de um arquivo CSV, a minha aplicação java precisa realizar a leitura deste CSV. 
De preferencia separar os dados em campos, para poder por exemplo adicionar estes em uma base de dados.

Após algumas pesquisas feitas na web, alguns exemplos que compreendi, no código java já traz os campos definido que o arquivo csv possui. É possível realizar a varredura do arquivo mesmo sem eu souber quantos campos a linha possui? Pois posso ter arquivos sendo enviado para a aplicação, com campos diferentes.

Comment: Independente da solução adotada (há 2 respostas enquanto escrevo), lembre-se de **sempre**, sempre mesmo, validar o tamanho do *array* obtido de uma entrada qualquer. Assim seu código ficará muito mais robusto. Caso contrário, se houver um imprevisto, como uma linha vazia ao final do arquivo (só para citar um exemplo), a implementação não vai quebrar.

Comment: Valeu pela dica @utluiz, realmente muito útil. Obrigado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Se fizer um split das linhas e um mapa ou até mesmo uma lista para guardar cada posição não terá problema, depois a cada linha é só fazer um loop interando por cada elemento resultante do split.

O exemplo abaixo é bastante simplificado, mas servirá para te dar um norte de como proceder veja, que posso pegar os ultimos elementos *"sem saber"* quantos possuem na linha. De forma análoga, terá de fazer um for até o pais.length para iterar sobre os diversos elementos do seu csv.

arquivo.csv

```
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
"1.0.8.0","1.0.15.255","16779264","16781311","CN","China"
"1.0.16.0","1.0.31.255","16781312","16785407","JP","Japão"
"1.0.32.0","1.0.63.255","16785408","16793599","BR","Brasil"
"1.0.64.0","1.0.127.255","16793600","16809983","JP","Japão"
"1.0.128.0","1.0.255.255","16809984","16842751","DK","Dinamarca"
```

stack.**LeiaCVS.java**

```
package stack;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LeiaCVS {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    LeiaCVS obj = new LeiaCVS();
    obj.run();

  }

  public void run() {

    String arquivoCSV = "arquivo.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String linha = "";
    String csvDivisor = ",";
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivoCSV));
        while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] pais = linha.split(csvDivisor);

            System.out.println("País [code= " + pais[pais.length-2] 
                                 + " , name=" + pais[pais.length-1] + "]");

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda @Kyllopardiun, vou adaptar meu código e testar esta implementação. Obrigado.

Answer (score 9):

Cara, você pode simplesmente usar o OpenCVS (http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Pra adaptar e usar ele basta usar o seguinte código:

```
public class ParseCSV {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
  //csv file containing data
  String strFile = "C:\\Users\\rsaluja\\CMS_Evaluation\\Drupal_12_08_27.csv";
  CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(strFile));
  String [] nextLine;
  int lineNumber = 0;
  while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    lineNumber++;
    System.out.println("Line # " + lineNumber);

    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[4] + "etc...");
  }
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, e sabe me dizer se usando o OpenCVS é possível eu ler campo por campo do CSV? Neste caso eu faria um laço de repetição dentro do while varrendo o nextLine[]?

Comment: No código passado, ele lê linha a linha do seu arquivo que foi carregado com o CSVReader e vai colocando no array chamado nextLine...você pode extrair as informações que você quer deles só passando a posição da linha que deseja (Como no final está nextLine[4]

Answer (score 6):

O código abaixo lê o os registros de um arquivo CSV, utilizando o OpenCSV.

Neste exemplo obtemos uma `List<String[]>`.

```
    Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("nome-do-arquivo.csv"));
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader)
                            .withSkipLines(1)//para o caso do CSV ter cabeçalho.
                            .build();

    List<String[]> linhas = csvReader.readAll();
    for (String[] linha : linhas)
        for (String[] coluna : linha)
            System.out.print(coluna + " # ");
        System.out.println();
```

**Importante:** Você precisa adicionar o OpenCSV como dependência no seu projeto. Se estiver usando o maven, basta adicionar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Referência: https://dicasdejava.com.br/como-ler-arquivos-csv-em-java/

Answer (score -6):

Use python, é mais facil.

```
import pandas as pd

magica = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv')

magica or magica.head()
```

:)

Comment: Se a pergunta foi feita em Java seja gentil e responda em Java. Proselitismo linguístico não interessa e é desnecessário.