# Em uma String separa com dados separados por ";" como pegar o 2º dado?

Tags: java

Tenho a string x = "Alberto;jose;Felipe;Ana". Eu precisava pegar o 2º dado, como faço isso? Agradeço desde já.

obs: A string x está dentro de um array de strings.

Comment: Não sou programador em Java, mas a lógica que você está querendo utilizar é semelhante a leitura de arquivos CSV, segue o link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27013/como-ler-arquivos-csv-em-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"Alberto;jose;Felipe;Ana".split(";")[1];
```

"split" retorna um array com todas as strings resultantes da "quebra" no caracter passado por parametro.

Comment: exatamente o que eu precisava, esqueci do detalhe que o split retorna um array.

Answer (score 2):

Para pegar os dados de uma string separado por "**;**" você pode utilizar o método `split` da própria variável string.

Exemplo:

```
String x = "Alberto;jose;Felipe;Ana";

String[] dadosSeparados = x.split(";");

for(String s : dadosSeparados){
    System.out.println("dado : "+s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a função split da classe string.

```
String frase =  "Alberto;jose;Felipe;Ana";
String[] array = frase.split(";");
```

Comment: `String array[]` não deveria ser `String[] array`? E só um adendo, esta linha `String[] array = new String[3];` é bem prolixa, você pode fazer direto  `String[] array = frase.split(";");`