# Divisão de arquivo CSV Java

Tags: java

Estou com um problema muito grade no uso de uso de arquivo CSV em Java, estou fazendo um trabalho e já fazem dias que não consigo ter uma ideia funcional pra essa parte, seguinte, tenho que criar uma rotina que receba um csv contendo os dados de mais de uma classe preenchido da seguinte forma:

```
class;id;nome;celular;email
Aluno;7;Alguem;21 12345678;eu@eu.com
Aluno;2;Fulano;31 4553;
Aluno;5;Sr. Beltrano;;tu@tu.com

class;nome;id
Turma;turma1;3
Turma;turma2;26
```

A primeira linha de cada grupo contem os dados que esta classe possui, o primeiro é o nome da classe e os outros são seus atributos, tenho que usar esses dados para preencher essas classes, só estou falando isso para entender a história por trás.
Preciso de alguma forma ler e separar esses grupos e de passa-los para um método que vai preencher isso(ainda não fiz ele), estou tentando ler o arquivo da seguinte forma:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(p, c);
```

Onde P é o path e c o Charset.Eu consigo andar pelas listas manipualr e tal,mas não estou conseguindo de forma alguma separar esses grupos em outra lista pra poder usar, já tentei muita coisa e como sou novo na linguagem com certeza existem métodos práticos de fazer isso que eu não achei em lugar nenhum.

Comment: tem somente um uma linha separado o arquivo?

Comment: exato, e podem ter mais de uma classes no arquivo, então entre cada classe fica uma linha vazia

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ler arquivos CSV em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27013/como-ler-arquivos-csv-em-java)

Comment: Eu vi esse post ai, só que ele simplismente quer separar usando o split, é um pouco diferente minha questão.

Comment: Se a ordem for aluno uma linha separando e depois a classe te aconselho a fazer o seguinte.
Leia o arquivo como uma string normal. Separe ele usando o split e depois percorra o array gerado, assim voce sabe que o primeiro é o aluno e depois a classe e depois o aluno e depois a classe. Assim sucessivamente.

Comment: A linha em branco só separa duas classes diferentes como esta ali em cima, onde esta "class;id;nome;celular;email" é a ordem que será dispostos os dados abaixo, só quando aparece a linha em branco é que se inicia uma classe nova, "class;nome;id"

Comment: Se eu não estivesse devendo duas respostas (que ainda estão em escrita), eu responderia esta com o maior prazer. Mas já vou logo avisando: dados heterogêneos no mesmo CSV não é auspicioso

Comment: Creio que recebi esse trabalho mesmo pra aprender a usar arquivos. A segunda parte de preencher os generics eu creio que sei fazer, essa separação dos dados que esta complicado.

Comment: Mas não percebo como a sua questão seja diferente. Itera cada uma das linhas que leu e usa `split`. Se olhar para o tamanho do array resultante consegue inclusivamente saber qual o tipo de linha em que está, para poder agir de forma diferente. Pessoalmente essa estrutura não me parece a melhor. Se tem classes diferentes melhor seria arquivos diferentes, cada um com a sua estrutura.

Answer (score 2):

Oi, primeiro tente padronizar seu CSV, defina o nome das colunas e uma vez definido tente não mexer mais nele como alterar as posições das colunas assim ficará mais fácil de manipular no lado do Java, por exemplo:

**class**;**id**;**nome**;**celular**;**email**
Aluno;7;Alguem;21 12345678;eu@eu.com
Aluno;2;Fulano;31 4553;
Aluno;5;Sr. Beltrano;;tu@tu.com

O que me vêm a cabeça é apenas o por que você decidiu usar no nome da classe em uma coluna, na minha opinião isso é uma má prática, tente encontrar alguma alternativa.

Para maniplar no Java você pode criar uma class POJO que vai ter apenas o nome das variáveis e seus respectivos getters e setters:

```
/**
 * Dados dos valores que contém no CSV
 */
public class Pojo {

    private String nomeDaClasse;

    private Integer oId;

    private String nome;

    private String numeroCelular;

    private String email;

    /**
     * @return the nomeDaClasse
     */
    public String getNomeDaClasse() {
        return nomeDaClasse;
    }

    /**
     * @param nomeDaClasse the nomeDaClasse to set
     */
    public void setNomeDaClasse(String nomeDaClasse) {
        this.nomeDaClasse = nomeDaClasse;
    }

    /**
     * @return the oId
     */
    public Integer getoId() {
        return oId;
    }

    /**
     * @param oId the oId to set
     */
    public void setoId(Integer oId) {
        this.oId = oId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nome
     */
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    /**
     * @param nome the nome to set
     */
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numeroCelular
     */
    public String getNumeroCelular() {
        return numeroCelular;
    }

    /**
     * @param numeroCelular the numeroCelular to set
     */
    public void setNumeroCelular(String numeroCelular) {
        this.numeroCelular = numeroCelular;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Agora é hora de ler o arquivo CSV, ler por linha, dividir o valor por ponto e vírgula e adicionar os valores no array da classe Pojo

```
/**
     * 
     * @param caminhoArquivo o caminho do arquivo que contém seu CSV
     * @param separador o separador do seu CSV, no caso ponto e virgula
     * @param temHeader se tem header, ou seja, o nome das colunas, então o código pula essa parte
     * @return os dados do CSV em um array
     * @throws IOException erro ao ler o arquivo
     */
    public static ArrayList<Pojo> lerCSV(String caminhoArquivo, String separador, boolean temHeader) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Pojo> pojos = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(caminhoArquivo))) {
            String linha;
            boolean eCabecalho = temHeader;
            while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (eCabecalho || linha.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    eCabecalho = false;
                    continue;
                }
                String[] colunas = linha.split(separador, 5); //Presumo que seu CSV tenha 5 colunas
                if (colunas.length != 5) {
                    System.out.println("O CSV tem mais ou menos de 5 colunas!");
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    String nomeDaClasse = colunas[0].trim();
                    Integer oId = Integer.parseInt(colunas[1].trim());
                    String nome = colunas[2].trim();
                    String numeroCelular = colunas[3].trim();
                    String email = colunas[4].trim();
                    System.out.println(nomeDaClasse + ";" + oId + ";" + nome + ";" + numeroCelular + ";" + email);
                    Pojo pojo = new Pojo(); 
                    pojo.setNomeDaClasse(nomeDaClasse);
                    pojo.setNome(nome);
                    pojo.setEmail(email);
                    pojo.setNumeroCelular(numeroCelular);
                    pojo.setoId(oId);
                    pojos.add(pojo);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Deu algum problema!\n " + ex);
                }

            }
        }

        return pojos;
    }
```